# UIButton Padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is there an equivalent padding for UIButton, just like in CSS?.

I seem to have a problem with small buttons so I want to expand the button size for it to be easily clickable.

I made a work around code to resize a UIButton and have the contents remain as they are supposed to be:

```
- (void)adjustButtonView:(UIButton *)button toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect previousFrame = button.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
    newFrame.size = size;
    CGFloat adjustX = (size.width - previousFrame.size.width)/2;
    CGFloat adjustY = (size.height - previousFrame.size.height)/2;
    newFrame.origin.x = previousFrame.origin.x - adjustX;
    newFrame.origin.y = previousFrame.origin.y - adjustY;
    button.frame = newFrame;

    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(adjustY, adjustX, adjustY, adjustX);
    button.contentEdgeInsets = edgeInsets;
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is an easier way to expand the UIButtons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easier way than what you did. But we can make your code better by moving the method to a UIButton category.

UIButton+Resize.h

```
@interface UIButton (Resize)

- (void)adjustToSize:(CGSize)size;

@end
```

UIButton+Resize.m

```
@implementation UIButton (Resize)

- (void)adjustToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGRect previousFrame = self.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.size = size;
    CGFloat adjustX = (size.width - previousFrame.size.width)/2;
    CGFloat adjustY = (size.height - previousFrame.size.height)/2;
    newFrame.origin.x = previousFrame.origin.x - adjustX;
    newFrame.origin.y = previousFrame.origin.y - adjustY;
    self.frame = newFrame;

    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(adjustY, adjustX, adjustY, adjustX);
    self.contentEdgeInsets = edgeInsets;
}

@end
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change 'button' to 'self'. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually, there is one stupidly simplistic way to expand the width of UIButtons if you don't want to mess with subclassing.... try this:

```
[b setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@  ", @"Title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing like CSS or style sheets for iOS, if you want to resize a button you'll have to do it manually setting the frame.

In order to automatize this task, you can create a button and subclass it, or use categories.